# Extra argument call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

The error is coming as: `Extra Argument "predicate" in Call`.
I am using it for searching in the array in an app.

The code is:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
   print(searchBar.text!)

   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)

   request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]

   loadItems(with: request, predicate: predicate)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: According to the code and the error message `loadItems` doesn't have a second parameter. You might assign the predicate to the request.

Comment: In the loadItems. Last line.

Comment: Why don't you assign the predicate to the request? `request.predicate = predicate`

Comment: Will look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the predicate to the request.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
   print(searchBar.text!)

   request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)

   request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]

   loadItems(with: request)

   self.tableView.reloadData() //for reloading the table view
}
```

And this should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The predicate is a property on the request, perhaps you meant

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
   
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)
   request.predicate = predicate
   request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]

   loadItems(with: request)
}
```